# How to pass a text file as input to Jython module from C++

Tags: c++, jython

I am working on a project in C++. After getting output as a text file from this C++ program, I want to produce an ontology (owl file) based on this output text file. For this, I need access to a python library (dendropy) and a java library (owlapi 5.1). I headed to Jython and successfully implemented the desired functionality (using Eclipse with PyDev).

The jython program takes input text file (which I previously saved to disc from C++ program) and saves required owl file to the disc.

Now I want to call jython module directly from the C++ program and pass the file/string to it and let it save the output file to the disc.

I searched for a solution and the only way I could find is to invoke the jython interpreter from command line and pass the input file to it. I want some better way of doing the same without involving command interpreter or batch scripts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to build your C++ program as a library and invoke it as a python module via `import`.
If you choose this solution, you can visit the `swig` program to generate an interface between your python module and c++ module.
More information [here](http://www.swig.org/index.php).